# How do I write unit test for below Presign function from AWS

Tags: go, testing, pre-signed-url

Given below is my function:

// GetPresignedURL generates a presigned URL for the specified object in S3

```
func GetPresignedURL(svc s3iface.S3API, bucketName, objectKey string, expirationTime int) (string, error) {
    req, _ := svc.GetObjectRequest(&s3.GetObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(bucketName),
        Key:    aws.String(objectKey),
    })

    // Set the expiration time for the presigned URL
    url, err := req.Presign(time.Duration(expirationTime) * time.Minute)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    return url, nil
}
```

> The above function cooks up a temporary, password-free URL for anyone
> to safely download the object before it expires.

I want to write a unit test for above function:

What I have tried:

```
package service

import (
    "testing"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/request"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3/s3iface"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/mock"
)

type MockS3API struct {
    mock.Mock
    s3iface.S3API
}

func (m *MockS3API) GetObjectRequest(input *s3.GetObjectInput) (*request.Request, *s3.GetObjectOutput) {
    args := m.Called(input)
    if args.Get(0) != nil {
        return args.Get(0).(*request.Request), args.Get(1).(*s3.GetObjectOutput)
    }
    return nil, nil
}

func TestGetPresignedURL(t *testing.T) {
    mockSvc := &MockS3API{}

    // Set up expected request and response
    expectedReq := &s3.GetObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String("my-bucket"),
        Key:    aws.String("my-object-key"),
    }
    expectedOutput := &s3.GetObjectOutput{} // you can set relevant output data here

    mockSvc.On("GetObjectRequest", expectedReq).Return(&request.Request{}, expectedOutput)

    url, err := GetPresignedURL(mockSvc, "my-bucket", "my-object-key", 60)

    // Assert the results
    assert.NoError(t, err)
    assert.NotNil(t, url)
    mockSvc.AssertExpectations(t)
}
```

Unfortunately I am getting error and my code is failing at line: `url, err := req.Presign(time.Duration(expirationTime) * time.Minute)`

Full error log:

> --- FAIL: TestGetPresignedURL (0.00s) panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference [recovered]     panic: runtime
> error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference [signal
> SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x6befe4]
>
> goroutine 6 [running]: testing.tRunner.func1.2({0x777ac0, 0xcf7850})
> /usr/local/go/src/testing/testing.go:1396 +0x24e
> testing.tRunner.func1()   /usr/local/go/src/testing/testing.go:1399
> +0x39f panic({0x777ac0, 0xcf7850})    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:884 +0x212
> github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/request.(*Request).copy(0xc0003fe500)
> /home/gullu/go/pkg/mod/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go@v1.49.16/aws/request/request.go:637
> +0x124 github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/request.(*Request).Presign(0xc00002c360?,
> 0xc000124630?)
> /home/gullu/go/pkg/mod/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go@v1.49.16/aws/request/request.go:332
> +0x1e imageservice/single-file-download-url/service.GetPresignedURL({0xa9af58,
> 0xc00002c360}, {0x7eb930, 0x9}, {0x7ed770, 0xd}, 0x3c)
> /home/gullu/tsproject/imageService/single-file-download-url/service/service.go:88
> +0x133 imageservice/single-file-download-url/service.TestGetPresignedURL(0x0?)
> /home/gullu/tsproject/imageService/single-file-download-url/service/service_test.go:103
> +0x20a testing.tRunner(0xc000143040, 0x82bee0)    /usr/local/go/src/testing/testing.go:1446 +0x10b created by
> testing.(*T).Run  /usr/local/go/src/testing/testing.go:1493 +0x35f
> FAIL  imageservice/single-file-download-url/service   0.009s

Comment: `req, _ := svc.GetObjectRequest` good place to start would be not ignoring errors.  Remember, Go doesn't have exceptions; your error return values are your chance to notice something went wrong.

Comment: can you please elaborate and explain in detail.

Comment: https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/handle-errors take a look at this page in the Go tutorial for information about handling errors.  It's quite essential to Go programming that you handle them yourself.  That whole tutorial is a must-read for new go programmers.